# Intellisense autocompletion for Javascript in VS Code not working

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, intellisense

I found that Visual Studio 2022 has a rich autocompletion feature, in particular it suggests methods and properties from DOM API, it smartly recognizes the type of variables and suggests the proper methods and so on.

### Visual Studio 2022 Experience

[image: Visual Studio Experience in Javascript]

### VS Code

In the highly-acclaimed vscode there is no autocomplete in javascript files, even though they say javascript is supported out of box. Please see the same code being written in vs code: no autocompletion at all!
[image: VS Code Experience in Javascript]

❓**Is it possible to have in vs code autocompletion like that in visual studio?**

Answer (score 0):

That file doesn't have an extension yet, so it's hard for the editor to detect the language

You can change the language manually from the status bar in the bottom, just click the button that says `Plain Text` and select JavaScript from the list

[image]

Comment: Thank for your answer. However, as you can see in the top left corner of the image, I have already select Javascript as language (see the JS icon).

Comment: VSCode has a built-in typescript extension to help itself with the intellisense, try selecting the querySelector and pressing f12 to see if it brings you a lib.dom.d.ts file.

Comment: I selected the word `querySelector` and pressed f12 but nothing happens. I have a fresh clean vscode.

Comment: Press F1 and type restart extension, then select Developer: Restart externsion host...

If it doesn't work you can either restart or you can install the JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly extension that overwrites the built-in one...

Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-next

Comment: maybe a silly question: do I need to install node.js or something like this?

Comment: I'm don't know if that could work, but It's worth trying, because the extension is stored in a node_modules folder.

Comment: Eventually, I found that there must be some strange configuration somewhere that caused the problem. Installing vscode in a different computer, it works fine out of box.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I found that there must be some strange configuration somewhere that caused the problem.
Installing vscode in a different computer, it works fine out of box.